# Объяснение пунктуации. Шекспир

Tags: пунктуация

Из шекспировской пьесы "Жизнь Тимона Афинского". Перевод П. И. Вейнберга. Речь живописца:

Да, я сумел // Жизнь передать недурно. Посмотрите // На этот штрих, -- (**?**) хорош?

Чем объясняется запятая и тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Посмотрите на этот штрих, — он хорош?**

Это БСП, второе предложение неполное, его полный вариант можно представить следующим образом: *Посмотрите на этот штрих (и скажите): он хорош?*

Двоеточие (по Розенталю) может заменять **единый знак "запятая и тире".**

**Из Розенталя:**

Вариативным стало употребление двоеточия и тире в эллиптических предложениях с отсутствующим глаголом восприятия (и увидел, и услышал, и почувствовал;
Прислушался: в горах было тихо.  *Прислушался - вековечная лесная тишина.*
**Иногда в этих случаях вместо двоеточия употребляются запятая и тире как единый знак**: *Я заглянул в гнёздышко, — там всего два птенчика* (Вер.); *Я обернулся, — всадник уже рядом* (Соб.); *Пoднял глаза, — стул подле стола был пустой* (Сер.).

[РАЗДЕЛ 19 Факультативные знаки препинания | xliby.ru](http://www.xliby.ru/jazykoznanie/spravochnik_po_russkomu_jazyku_punktuacija/p19.php)